# Can I use two series of commas in the same phrase or sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

### Example phrase: Which one may be correct?

> rich, strong, and fast **man,** white **woman,** **boy, and girl**

Coordinating four nouns "man, woman, boy, and girl" whatever the places of modifiers.

> rich, strong, and fast man and white woman, boy, and girl**

The conjunction "and" is coordinating two noun phrases whatever the places of modifiers.

Comment: The second option might suggest that the "white woman" is rich and strong, while the boy and girl are not. What is actually meant by the sentence?

Comment: I'm just waiting to see what kind of sentence could ever require this collection to be expressed before I comment any further.

Comment: You can use as many series of commas as you like in a single phrase or sentence. Taming them to say what you intend, though, that's the trick.

Comment: Is this one list or two?

Comment: Also notice you don't typically use "and" in a list of adjectives modifying the same noun.

Comment: Your problem is not commas, it's missplaced adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option of using semi-colons as higher-level separators but I wouldn't bother with anything as simple as your first example. I might for something like:

> rich, ugly, old man; thin, young, white woman; and pretty, poor girl.

Answer (score 1):

> There was a rich, ugly, old man, a thin, young, white woman, and a
>   pretty, poor girl.

Comment: Oh, you did it.